# ReactJS - Disable Click & Hold for Context menu for mobile without disabling click events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, contextmenu

I'm making a game in ReactJS where I'm using a long press event to perform certain actions in the game (using react-click-n-hold for long press events). When I do these actions on a mobile browser, it always brings up the context menu. How can I disable the context menu on mobile without disabling my click and long press events?

Answer (score 5):

```
<div onContextMenu={(e)=> e.preventDefault()}... />
```

This solution from [Max Svid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7554092/max-svid) worked for me

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56328162/12722618

Answer (score 1):

Kinda late to the topic
I found the *holdToDisplay* flag of the ContextMenuTrigger element reading the  [API](https://github.com/vkbansal/react-contextmenu/blob/d9018dbfbd6e21423cb2b753b3762adf5a6d77b0/docs/api.md).
Basically, if you set the flag to -1, the trigger is disabled if you hold the click (set to 1000ms by default).

```
<ContextMenuTrigger id='menu_id' holdToDisplay={-1}>
  // ...
</ContextMenuTrigger>
```

Although I admit I haven't tested on mobile browsers.
Hope it helps future readers